# How can you use cocoapod framework into another cocoapod created locally?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Specifically:

1. Created a new project
2. Setup CocoaPods
3. To the Pod file under Pods I added a dependency (for ex.AlamoFire)
4. The main app which consumes the pods can import Alamofire
5. The local cocoapod which I created and added by using the following lines in the podfile:

   `target 'SomeValue' do
       my_own_pod
       pod 'CocoaPod_2', :path => '/LocalPath/To/PodSource'
   end`
6. Ran pod install and I added the AlamoFire Framework to the CocoaPod_2 under Pods -> General-> CocoaPod_2-> Linked Libraries & Binaries
7. At this point I was expecting that importing Alamofire in my CocoaPod_2 will work fine but its not.

Screenshot of the workspace :

`MyProject.XCWorkspace
|_MyProject.App
  |____Source Code files importing CocoaPod_1 (Embedded using CocoaPod)
  |____Source Code files importing CocoaPod_2 (Embedded using CocoaPods, local Pod)
|_Pods
  |____Podfile
  |____Frameworks
  |____Pods
       |___CocoaPod_1
           |___CocoaPod_1 Source Files
           |____Source Code for Local Pod
  |___CocoaPod_2
       |____File contains statement (import cocoapod_1) <---Gives error ld: framework not found`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following two additional things:

- You need to add a Podfile in your CocoaPod_2 followed by a `pod install`.
- Also, you need to define a CocoaPod_2.podspec file in your CocoaPod_2
  folder.

If you add `Alamofire` in both the Podfile and podspec file of CocoaPod_2, you don't need to add in the main app's Podfile. Only adding CocoaPod_2 entry in the app's Podfile will suffice.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! My reputation is not enough that my upvote will be counted. Appreciate your response.